#   jtable reloads but when clicked on a jcheck box old data popsup

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i) My Table contains no of columns and a jcheckbox i the last column. 
ii) I am using a combobox to select certain value.
iii) based on the value of combo box the jbutton loads the data into the table.
iv) when i ***reload*** the data into the table, the new data gets displayed in jtable.
v) The problem is that, When I press the Jcheckbox, the old data is getting displayed in jtable.
 code is as below:

```
 public class aap2 extends JFrame {
      @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
      static JComboBox year = new JComboBox(new Object[]
          {"2012-13", "2013-14", "2014-15", "2015-16","2016-17","2017-       
                       18","2018-19"});
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
static JComboBox division = new JComboBox(new Object[]
          {"Name", "address","profession","others"});
JComboBox schemetype = new JComboBox(new Object[]
          {});

JButton showschemes = new JButton("Show Schemes");

static ResultSet rs;
Connection con;
Statement st;
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
static JPanel panel2= new JPanel();
static JPanel panel3= new JPanel();
static JPanel panel4= new JPanel();
static JPanel panel5= new JPanel();
UIManager ui= new UIManager();
static int columns;
static int sel[];
JTable table;
DefaultTableModel dtm;
public aap2(){
    division.setMaximumRowCount(5);
    year.setMaximumRowCount(5);
    year.setForeground(Color.blue);
    year.setBackground(Color.white);
    year.setSelectedItem("2009-10");

    setBounds(00,40,1020,700);
    Color c= new Color(160,200,100);
    getContentPane().setBackground(c);
    Color c3= new Color(0,50,50,2);
    panel1.setBackground(c3);
    panel2.setBackground(c3);
    panel.setBackground(c);
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.white,1),""));
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc= new GridBagConstraints();

    panel1.setLayout( new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc1 = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc1.gridx=0;
    gc1.gridy=0;
    panel1.add( new JLabel("Financial Year"),gc1);
    gc1.insets= new Insets(1,10,1,10);
    gc1.gridx=1;
    gc1.gridy=0;
    panel1.add(year,gc1);

    gc1.gridx=4;
    gc1.gridy=0;
    panel1.add( new JLabel("Division"),gc1);
    gc1.gridx=5;
    gc1.gridy=0;
    panel1.add(division,gc1);
    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=0;
    panel.add(panel1,gc);


    JPanel p2= new JPanel();
    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=4;
    p2.setBackground(c3);
    panel.add(p2,gc);

    panel3.setLayout( new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc3 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc3.insets= new Insets(30,10,1,10);
    gc3.gridx=0;
    gc3.gridy=2;
    panel3.add(showschemes,gc3);
    showschemes.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                showschemsActionPerformed(e);
            }
    });

    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=5;
    panel3.setBackground(c3);
    panel.add(panel3,gc);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setUndecorated(true);
    getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);  

        }

   public void showschemsActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        showtable();

     }
        public void showtable() {
    final Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    final Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
          try{
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
             System.out.println("Driver loaded");

             // Establish a connection
           con= DriverManager.getConnection
               ("jdbc:odbc:ysr");
             System.out.println("Database connecteddddd");

             // Create a statement
             st = con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ysr2011 where=  
                      '"+division.getSelectedItem()+"' ");

             ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();

    columns = md.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println("col" +(columns+1));
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
    columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
    }
    columnNames.addElement("Save");
    while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) { 
    row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
    }
    row.addElement(new Boolean(false));
    data.addElement( row );
    }
      rs.close();
             con.close();
             st.close();
      }
    catch(Exception e1){}
          dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
      public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
        if(col==columns){
            return Boolean.class;
        }else{
            return String.class;
        }
        }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
    return (colIndex == columns);
            }
        };

       dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
       table= new JTable(dtm); ; 

    table.setFont(new Font(" Arial",Font.PLAIN,12));
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    header.setFont(new Font(" Arial",Font.BOLD,12));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    JButton button= new JButton("Save");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
                Boolean b = ((Boolean) table.getValueAt(row, columns));
                 if (b.booleanValue()) {
                    System.out.print("row " + row + " is " + b + ": ");
                     for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                        System.out.print(table.getValueAt(row, col) + " ");
                       }
                       System.out.println();
                  }
              }

           }
        });

    JPanel buttonpanel= new JPanel();
    buttonpanel.add(button);
    add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonpanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Color c1= new Color(160,200,100);
    table.setBackground(c1);
    buttonpanel.setBackground(c1);
    setBackground(c1);
    setVisible(true);  
    }


public static void main(String args[]){
new aap2();
      }

    }
```

Comment: Show us your real source code. This one doesn't compile, and we can't know if the errors it contains are real or fake. We need a SSCCE.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: Post properly formatted code. That is use either tabs or spaces for indentation and be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to change the data in your table, try to create a new `DefaultTableModel` object (or any other object that implements the `TableModel` interface), and call `table.setModel(yourNewModel);`

Comment: *"why does firetabledatachanged() does not work."*  To find an answer to that, please, ***post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).***